# Can Eclipse workspace resolution be used with annotation processors/code generators?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apt

I am not trying to use, but to develop a new annotation processor that generates code, much like Dagger or Lombok. While everything is working fine if I compile things from command line and make the APT project a maven dependency, I can not get it to work if I have two projects in Eclipse.

The workspace resolution that works so well otherwise seems to be unable to understand the APT nature of my APT project, so it just gets added as a normal dependency. A workaround that works but is clumsy and error prone is to build a jar off the APT project, and then to have a system scope dependency in my other project, so it seems like it is technically possible.

Any hints on how I can end up with a fluid integration where changes to the APT project are reflected in the project that attempts to use the APT without having to manually run maven builds or refreshes in between ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in the package explorer, pick **Properties**.

Open up the **Java Compiler** section, and pick **Annotation Processing**.

Pick *Enable project specific settings*, then tick both *Enable annotation processing* and *Enable processing in editor*.

Then, open up the **Annotation Processing** section, and pick **Factory path**.

Click *Add jar...* (or possibly *Add external jar...*; depends on how your project is set up) and add the jar that is the annotation processor.

Hit ok, say yes to the offer to rebuild it all, and from here on out, anytime you save an editor, the annotation processor is run.

You can't do the lombok magic (which runs after you stop typing, even if you do not save); lombok is awesome hackery.